# Can you find the set for these Star Wars space ship parts? Dark grey with some dark grey detailing?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

Just wondering if someone can identify these parts so I can locate the correct instructions.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The set is 7673, The MagnaGuard Starfighter.

[image]

Instructions are [here](http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/4536958.pdf).

I was able to verify the dimensions of the cockpit piece using Lego Digital Designer.  Once I knew it was 4x8x3, I was able to use [brickset.com](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4527146) to identify the set as this piece only appeared in one set.

Answer (score 2):

These are part of [7673-1: MagnaGuard Starfighter](https://brickset.com/sets/7673-1/MagnaGuard-Starfighter).

[image]